# How to prove that below quantity is purely imaginary?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, gauss-sums

How do I prove that the following quantity is purely imaginary:

$$\sum_{0\leq l_1<l_2<l_3<l_4\leq q-1} e^{-2\pi i \frac{(l_1^2-l_2^2+l_3^2-l_4^2)}{q} } $$ where $q$ is an odd number?

Comment: Here $q$ "is" an odd number. No assumtions. The above quantity is imaginary for $q$ odd, which can be verified using a machine but I want to prove it analytically.

Comment: Maybe try to show it is invariant under sending $a+bi$ to $-a+bi$.

Comment: or better: try to show that complex conjugation results in multiplying by $-1$!

Comment: @M.Van Yeah, I have tried to sum up the quantity and its conjugate and simplify the expression. But, couldn't succeed.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: or try squaring it

Comment: It seems to be $0$ for $q$ prime.

Comment: @lhf That could be. Actually, it's part of a problem where I need to compare the real parts of two terms let's say A and B=B'+B'', so we've real(A) = real(B') + real(B''). Here, if B'' is purely imaginary or zero then we've real(A) = real(B') which is desired. In this case, B'' is term mentioned above.

Comment: That made me feel old. Any way to enlarge that summation without also enlarging all the other text on this page?